itext cut pdf by Rectangle
I used itext7 to cut the PDF. For example, I cut a page of PDF into two parts based on the Rectangle coordinates, pdf1 and pdf2. I read the text of pdf1 and obtained the entire page
  using (PdfDocument outputPdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer))
  {
      PdfPage page = pdfDocument.GetPage(pageNumber);
      page.SetMediaBox(new Rectangle(cropRectangle));
      outputPdfDocument.AddPage(page.CopyTo(outputPdfDocument));
  }

This is the code I cropped
I hope you can tell me how to solve this problem or how to modify it

"I hope you can tell me how to solve this problem" - What actually is the problem? As far as I read your question, you merely state facts but don't say which one is not desired.
